# Inline-block isn't working in image gallery

Tags: css, image, gallery, sections

I have a image gallery in a website I'm working on.
Instead of float, I need to use inline-block on each image container so that I can center the entire gallery later(I found I would never be able to center floated images after so many try-outs)
I'd be appreciated a million times if anybody find flaws in my code.
(For the record, I used float on a top navigation above the image gallery. Please tell me if it affected the gallery any how!)

> > > This is html code for image gallery.

```
   <section>
        <article class="img1">
            <a href=""><img src="img/img1.png"></a>
            <dl>
                <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
                <dd>Image Description</dd>
            </dl>
        </article>
        <article class="img2">
            <a href=""><img src="img/img2.png"></a>
            <dl>
                <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
                <dd>Image Description</dd>
            </dl>
        </article>
        <article class="img3">
            <a href=""><img src="img/img3.png"></a>
            <dl>
                <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
                <dd>Image Description</dd>
            </dl>
        </article>
```

> > > This is css code for image gallery.

```
section{
    margin-top: 80px; /* the gap between top navigation above */
}

article .img1, .img2, .img3 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 2%;
    padding: 0;
}

article img{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

article dl{
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

article dt{
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 400; 
}

article dd{
    margin-left: 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 300; 
}
```

Comment: One more question ;-) I wanted to center the image gallery, so I added 'text-align:center' to 'section'. It works fine, but what I want is to center the entire gallery and left align each images inside it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting a `width` of `100%` on the `<article>` elements, so although they're set to `display: inline-block`, they each take up `100%` of the row. To avoid this, you'll want to give them a smaller percentage-based width, ideally with `width: calc((100% / 3) - (2% * 3))`. This sets them to take up as much width as possible, while accounting for both the number of elements and also the `margin-left` on each.

Also note that your `<img>` tags have a hard-coded fixed `width`. Because you're now adjusting your containing `<article>` tags to be relative to the container, these images should be given a `width` of `100%`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
section {
  margin-top: 80px;
  /* the gap between top navigation above */
}

.img1,
.img2,
.img3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - (2% * 3));
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 2%;
  padding: 0;
}

article img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

article dl {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

article dt {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

article dd {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="img1">
    <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100"></a>
    <dl>
      <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
      <dd>Image Description</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
  <article class="img2">
    <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100"></a>
    <dl>
      <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
      <dd>Image Description</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
  <article class="img3">
    <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100"></a>
    <dl>
      <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
      <dd>Image Description</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh....Thank you so much!!! It works perfectly! Thanks again for your detailed explanation!